# Apache Tomcat 9.0.40 server throws 404 error when ran on eclipse. otherwise it works fine

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I am trying to learn jsp-apache web server - oracle db interconnectivity.
I installed Apache and gave it 10407 port and when I run it in windows command line 'startup'
server starts and I can connect to localhost:10407 website successfully.
But, when I try to do the same thing in Eclipse, (only one apache is installed in my computer atm)
Console shows same messages and it connects to server. But when I try to access localhost:10407,
it throws this error.

```
HTTP Status 404 – Not Found
Type Status Report

Message The requested resource [/] is not available

Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: What's even more killing me is that old projects are working fine with apache web server, it's just the new one that throw 404 error. New Dynamic Web project with only empty index.html file throws 404 Error and I have no clue what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It was a mistake. I put `index.html` file in `WEB-INF` folder.